# iptables logging prefix gets corrupted

Tags: iptables, syslog

I've been using `iptables` for some time but recently noticed that the log prefix I'd set had got corrupted. In /etc/iptables/rules.v4` I have:

```
-A LOGNDROP -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
```

I found that in `/var/log/syslog` I actually have records like

```
Jul 25 20:10:04 zotac kernel: [688421.696561] --log-prefixIN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=1c:4b:d6:ee:a9:64:00:24:17:0c:a7:ef:08:00 SRC=173.194.67.109 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=44 ID=36871 PROTO=TCP SPT=587 DPT=60497 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Where the log prefix has somehow got set to `--log-prefix`.I can fix this by executing:

```
 ~# iptables -R LOGNDROP 1 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
```

But why is this happening and how do I fix it?

FYI: `Debian Wheezy [Linux version 3.2.0-2-686-pae (Debian 3.2.20-1)]` with `iptables [1.4.14-2]` and `iptables-persistent [0.5.3+nmul]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's a bug in `iptables-restore`.

See [here on bugzilla](http://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774) or [here on Debian bugs](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=678499)

Basically, `iptables-restore` can't parse arguments in double quotes (which is what `iptables-save` writes the log prefix as) so picks up the previous token, which is the string `--log-prefix` itself!

The solution is to upgrade to iptables 1.4.14-3 (currently in Debian sid/unstable).